# Cambiar colores del donut chart

Tags: python, color, plotly

¿Cómo puedo cambiar los colores del donut chart en plotly?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go


labels= ['2017','2018']
values= [23.80, 76.20]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, hole=.3)])  
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `update_traces(marker=dict(colors=lista_de_colores))`:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

labels= ['2017','2018']
values= [23.80, 76.20]
colors=['green','orange']
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, hole=.3)])  
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(colors=colors))
fig.show()
```

[image: Gráfico circular con nuevos colores (naranjo y verde)]